# How to collapse all div and dynamically change the button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a page with collapse function, but I can only achieve single div collapse by boostrap. How to write a function to collapse all div and change the button content like "Collapse all-" to "Expand all+"?

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-poincare-skugzl

```
          <div class="p-3 text-end">
            <a class="text-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#question">Collapse All-</a>
          </div>
           <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#q11">
            <div class="bg-light rounded position-relative mt-4">
              <div class="container-fluid p-4 overflow-hidden">
                <span class="d-inline-block fw-bold">1. What should I do ?</span>
                <span class="float-end fw-bold">+</span>
                <div class="collapse mt-3" id="q11">
                  <p class="mb-0">
                    Please help.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </a>
          <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#q12">
          <div class="bg-light rounded position-relative mt-4">
            <div class="container-fluid p-4 overflow-hidden">
              <span class="d-inline-block fw-bold">2. What should I do?</span>
              <span class="float-end fw-bold">+</span>
              <div class="collapse mt-3" id="q12">
                <p class="mb-0">
                  please help
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle the `show` class:

```
function changeVisibility(){
   document.querySelectorAll(".collapse").forEach(div => div.classList.toggle("show"))
}
```

[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-brook-kg4syq?file=/index.html)